# Does exec() command in matlab handle several sql statements?

Tags: mysql, matlab

I'm trying to run

curs=exec(conn,['SET @rank=0;select @rank+1']);

in Matlab, but the cursor says there is a problem with syntax. However, when I run it in MySQL it has no problem. any suggestion? both statement works fine separately.
(It is a minimal instance, I cut the second select to be clear where the problem come from)
Thanks

Comment: Oh, so there is "a problem with syntax", hm? Okay, let me just quickly ask my crystal ball what problem. And, while I am at it, I'll also ask what exactly you are trying to do here.

Comment: I need the @rank  variable to return the place of a row in an ORDER BY statement, without it everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is with the exec command where it only returns the first statement result. Since in the first statement I have no result, it returns an error. More info on the [workarounds](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101807-how-can-i-execute-a-complex-set-of-sql-commands-at-once-with-database-toolbox)